# ORA-01034: ORACLE not available happened when oracle deployment from Docker official image

Tags: oracle, docker

When I deployed from this image with oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/11.2.0.2
Then I faced

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
```

docker-compose.yml was

```
version: '2'
services:
  oracle:
    build: dockerfile
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "8080:8080"
    shm_size: 1G
    volumes:
     - ./oradata:/u01/app/oracle/oradata
    environment: 
      - ORACLE_PWD=passwd
      - ORACLE_PDB=PDB01
      - ORACLE_SID=SID01
```

under dockerfile directory was (just checked out from [github](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/11.2.0.2))

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 abe 1049089       999 Feb  3 16:35 checkDBStatus.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 abe 1049089      3107 Feb  3 16:37 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 abe 1049089 315891481 Feb  3 14:31 oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 abe 1049089      7088 Feb  3 16:35 runOracle.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 abe 1049089       193 Feb  3 16:35 setPassword.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 abe 1049089      2943 Feb  3 16:35 xe.rsp
```

boot log was

```
oracle_1  | ORACLE PASSWORD FOR SYS AND SYSTEM: passwd
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Configuration
oracle_1  | -------------------------------------------------
oracle_1  | This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 11g Express
oracle_1  | Edition.  The following questions will determine whether the database should
oracle_1  | be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that
oracle_1  | will be used for database accounts.  Press <Enter> to accept the defaults.
oracle_1  | Ctrl-C will abort.
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:
oracle_1  | Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:
oracle_1  | Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
oracle_1  | password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of
oracle_1  | different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after
oracle_1  | initial configuration:
oracle_1  | Confirm the password:
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:
oracle_1  | Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
oracle_1  | Configuring database...Done
oracle_1  | Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done
oracle_1  | Installation completed successfully.
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Feb 4 10:21:22 2020
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | Connected to an idle instance.
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL> BEGIN DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE); END;
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL> SQL>       ALTER DATABASE ADD LOGFILE GROUP 4 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/SID01/redo04.log') SIZE 50m
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  | 
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL>       ALTER DATABASE ADD LOGFILE GROUP 5 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/SID01/redo05.log') SIZE 50m     
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL>       ALTER DATABASE ADD LOGFILE GROUP 6 ('/u01/app/oracle/oradata/SID01/redo06.log') SIZE 50m     
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  | 
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL>       ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  | 
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL>       ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL>       ALTER SYSTEM CHECKPOINT
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL>       ALTER DATABASE DROP LOGFILE GROUP 1
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL>       ALTER DATABASE DROP LOGFILE GROUP 2
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL> SQL>       ALTER SYSTEM SET db_recovery_file_dest=''
oracle_1  | *
oracle_1  | ERROR at line 1:
oracle_1  | ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
oracle_1  | Process ID: 0
oracle_1  | Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  |
oracle_1  | SQL> Disconnected
oracle_1  | mv: cannot stat '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/spfileSID01.ora': No such file or directory      
oracle_1  | mv: cannot stat '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/orapwSID01': No such file or directory
oracle_1  | #########################
oracle_1  | DATABASE IS READY TO USE!
oracle_1  | #########################
oracle_1  | The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
oracle_1  | QMNC started with pid=24, OS id=481
oracle_1  | Completed: ALTER DATABASE OPEN
oracle_1  | Tue Feb 04 10:21:12 2020
oracle_1  | db_recovery_file_dest_size of 10240 MB is 0.98% used. This is a
oracle_1  | user-specified limit on the amount of space that will be used by this
oracle_1  | database for recovery-related files, and does not reflect the amount of
oracle_1  | space available in the underlying filesystem or ASM diskgroup.
oracle_1  | Starting background process CJQ0
oracle_1  | Tue Feb 04 10:21:12 2020
oracle_1  | CJQ0 started with pid=26, OS id=495
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the guides on the error you have? For example http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01034_oracle_not_available.htm

Comment: shared memory has already been set
  shm_size: 1G

Comment: SQL> conn system/passwd@localhost:1521/XE
Connected.

This could be worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself.

ORACLE_PDB, ORACLE_SID cannot be created automatically with those parameters.
On the first deployment, we should set `ORACLE_PWD` only.
After deployment, we can access to the DB `sqlplus system/${ORACLE_PWD}@XE`.